# Linking drop down menu to a new form in MS Access

Tags: ms-access

I created a drop-down menu with 3 selections.  I need to link each selection to open up a new form so that the user will have choices for each selection. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You've got quite a short vague question there, in this answer I'm assuming that by "drop-down menu" you mean combo box.

On the "Change" event for your combo box, have a select case statement that has case statements corresponding to each value that your combo box could take.  For each case statement have a DoCmd.OpenForm("FormName".....) statement for each form you would like to open.

If you want a more specific answer, please post a more specific/detailed question (with code you've tried).

Answer (score 0):

If the selections in your combo box contain the actual form names you want to open, you can do this with a single statement in the combo box's "On Change" or "After Update" event:

```
DoCmd.OpenForm Combo1.Value
```

If the values in your combo box will be different than the form names you want to open, you can write a select statement:

```
Select Case Combo1.Value
    Case "Option1"
        DoCmd.OpenForm "Form 1 Name"
    Case "Option2"
        DoCmd.OpenForm "Form 2 Name"
    Case "Option3"
        DoCmd.OpenForm "Form 3 Name"
End Select
```